# Self answered questions appear the wrong way round in the profile page (and other places)

Tags: bug, status-declined, profile-page, self-answer, time

[Self answered questions have misordered timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254329/self-answered-questions-have-misordered-timeline). Because it is old tech that may go it is not gong to be repaired. However...

[image]

This is from the profile page 0 the Answer comes before (well after, before in time) the Question.

They both have exactly the same UTC-time-hover, so perhaps posting the answer 1 second later would solve this issue?

Comment: Given that the question and answer were posted at the same exact instant, they have the exact same timestamp. Your screen shot, however, shows the question before the answer - is that what you are trying to say is wrong?

Comment: It shows the Answer before, it is lower down... It thinks the Answer is older.

Comment: They both have the same exact "age". It can be argued that having the exact same time stamp, either one should be first.

Answer (score 7):

As both Question and Answer have the same posted time in a Self Answered question, showing the Question or Answer in any order is correct - "*based on time*".

However, I can see why you still want a Q before A in listings even for a Self Answered, because for an Answer to exist you need a Question, and so logically an Answer should come *after* a Question.

There is the other argument, that this is "Self Answered" and not a "normal" Q&A, and so there are differences. 
In this case an Answer does not come after a Question, they *do* come at the same time.
However, arguments aside, I would say that it's *better* for us (most) "humans" to see a Q before an A in listings.
It just seems more logical and "comfortable" that way.

**Not a bug:**
I'd argue this is not a bug though, it's by-design as the system simply lists things based on time.
So I would assume if you want to get it changed you'd need a feature request.

---

**Options:**

1. Answer's post time in Self Answered to be advanced to after the
   Question's post time
2. Relevant list scripts identify Self Answered questions and list Q
   before A
3. Relevant lists *visually* identify when a Q or A is from
   a Self Answered

(1)
I disagree with advancing the time of the Answer.
This is not correct, as they are by nature and logic posted "at the same time" and should therefore have the same post times.

If the time is advanced by only a short amount it might appear to be a delay in the scripts.
If time was advanced too much, say 10 mins, they would just look like a normal Q&A pair. i.e. `[Q 08:00]` and `[A 08:10]`.

Users may see this as "wrong" and possibly raise questions - "Answer should have same time as Question" or "why are they not the same time".

(2)
While this is the *better* option, it would mean additional script time on each and every view of a page with relevant Q&A listings.

I have no idea of overhead on this though, perhaps small enough to give a good enough ROI.

(3)
This retains the logic that Self Answered Question and Answer have the same time.
And would *help* towards removing confusion of seeing an Answer before the Question it answered, because their being visually identified as a Self Answered Q or A would bring sense/explanation to the situation.

This could simply be having "Self" stamped somewhere on any Q and A from a Self Answered Question.

Or the current speech bubbles around the Q's and A's could be a different image - something along the lines of the Ouroboros (I know that won't happen, of course, but a nice idea..).

Answer (score -2):

Self answered questions mean that the question and the answer were posted at exactly the same time.

As far as the system is concerned, one is not older than the other and can be displayed in any order.

Comment: But answer can't exist on its own without a question. Common sense says that first the question is created, then it's being answered. So I would expect a manual "patch" in such cases. And profile page is way more important than timeline view.

Comment: I think that this deserves reconsideration... It should be the correct way round, esp on the profile page.

Comment: This is true, technically, and based on "times" only, but there's more to it than that. People logically want to see Q before A, rightly or wrongly, that is the way it is.

Comment: So, how much rep you want in exchange for reconsidering? ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Doubt there is a bounty big enough ;)